# Linux SSH disconnects and mouse left click and scroll pastes weird sequences

Tags: linux, ssh

I use a Linux server at work and connect via iTerm and SSH. I've noticed that if I leave it idle for a while then it disconnects while giving the message `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`, disconnecting my SSH connection. Afterwards my mouse left click pastes random sequences like `81;37M0;81;37m` (the sequence is different for every click). The same happens when I scroll up or down.

Does anybody know why this happens? And is there a way that I can prevent this?

Comment: Try this command:  `tput rmcup`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti That command doesn't do anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

These are mouse events data. Try input `reset`. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and when I observe it works I'll accept your answer. Do you know why this happens only sometimes? What I mean is that when my server disconnects, I only get these displayed on my screen half of the time.